# Joi - Invalid Regular Expression

Tags: node.js, regex, joi

```
/^(?! )(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)([a-zA-Z\d!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ]{8,})(?<! )$/
```

Works perfectly in regex101.com, chrome console and even joi npm runkit. But when used in code Joi is giving error as -

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: {above regex}: Invalid Group
```

Can u please help me with this??

Comment: `(?<! )`  is a lookbehind and currently it only works in Chrome (supporting ECMAScript 2018).

Comment: I tried that in joi npm runkit. it works perfectly but when used in code it is giving me the error

Comment: Use [this fix](https://regex101.com/r/fyODHu/1).

Comment: Solved the issue by just updating my npm library

Comment: thanx @WiktorStribiżew your solution helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that browsers that do not support ECMAScript 2018 do not support lookbehinds in regular expressions.

The pattern you have contains `(?<! )` negative lookbehind that checks if there is no space at the end of the string (it stands before `$` anchor).

Hence, you may fix it by replacing that lookbehind with `(?=.*\S$)` (requires a non-whitespace char at the end of the string) or `(?!.*\s$)` (disallows a whitespace at the end of the string) *lookaheads* that are supported by the popular ES5 standard.